# Install PHP 7 on different folder with PHP 5.6 already installed

Tags: apache2, php, amazon-ec2, php7, php-fpm

I have a EC2 instance on Amazon AWS based on "Bitnami Wordpress 4.4.2-1" AMI with "Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-77-generic x86_64)" in eu-west-1 (Ireland) region.

This AMI has PHP 5.6 (php-fpm) with Apache already installed. I want to install PHP 7 on separate directory and safety change the Apache PHP handle from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7 (and in case of problem re-change PHP handle from PHP 7 to 5.6).

Is this possible?

Comment: try this in defrent machine first, but, as i know php7 will be installed in `/etc/php/7.0/` but php5 will be out of `7.0` directory, also you need to change the php apache module from `php5` to `php7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Each PHP version is installed in its own directory, so don't worry about this.

1. Install the new PHP version:

   ```
   sudo apt install php7.0-fpm
   ```
2. Edit virtualhost's config file (the default is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`). Between `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `</VirtualHost>`, add the following code:

   ```
   <FilesMatch \.php$>
       <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
           SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
       </If>
   </FilesMatch>
   ```
3. Restart the Apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

If you want to go back to your the previous version, just remove the code from Step 2 and restart the Apache.